# Algorithm for writing to EEPROM?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I have a memory which is a column of 4 byte rows. I can only **write** to it **in 16 bytes** and read is done in 4 bytes (line by line, that is) using I2C.

I am interested in how to write data into the EEPROM: the data that is being written consists of a few different parts of which two can be of variable length. For example, I can have XYYZ or XYYYYZZZZZZZ where each letter is 4 bytes.

My question is, how I should go about this problem to have a general way of writing the message to the memory using 16 byte write that would accommodate the variable nature of the two parts?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try to work in 4 or 16-byte units, you could consider using a small (21-byte) static cache for the eeprom. Let's assume you have

```
void eeprom_read16(uint32_t page, uint8_t *data);
void eeprom_write16(uint32_t page, const uint8_t *data);
```

where `page` is the address divided by 16, and always operate on 16 byte chunks. The cache itself and its initialization function (you'd call once at power-on) would be

```
static uint32_t eeprom_page;      /* uint16_t suffices for 2 MiB EEPROM */
static uint8_t  eeprom_cache[16];
static uint8_t  eeprom_dirty;

static void eeprom_init(void)
{
    eeprom_page  = 0x80000000U; /* "None", at 32 GiB */
    eeprom_dirty = 0;
}

static void eeprom_flush(void)
{
    if (eeprom_dirty) {
        eeprom_write16(eeprom_page, eeprom_cache);
        eeprom_dirty = 0;
    }
}
```

The `eeprom_flush()` function is only needed if you wish to ensure some data is stored in the EEPROM -- basically, after each complete transaction. You can safely call it at any time.

To access any memory in the EEPROM, you use the accessor functions

```
static inline uint8_t eeprom_get(const uint32_t address)
{
    const uint32_t page = address >> 4;
    if (page != eeprom_page) {
        if (eeprom_dirty) {
            eeprom_write(eeprom_page, eeprom_cache);
            eeprom_dirty = 0;
        }
        eeprom_read(page, eeprom_cache);
        eeprom_page = page;
    }
    return eeprom_cache[address % 0xFU];
}

static inline void eeprom_set(const uint32_t address, const uint8_t value)
{
    const uint32_t page = address >> 4;
    if (page != eeprom_page) {
        if (eeprom_dirty) {
            eeprom_write(eeprom_page, eeprom_cache);
            eeprom_dirty = 0;
        }
        eeprom_read(page, eeprom_cache);
        eeprom_page = page;
    }
    eeprom_dirty = 1;
    eeprom_cache[address % 0xFU] = value;
}
```

Feel free to omit the `inline` if you like; it is just an optimization. The `static inline` above tell a C99 compiler to inline the functions if possible. It might increase a bit your code size, but it should produce faster code (because the compiler can make better optimizations when such small functions are inlined into the code).

Note that you should not use the above in interrupt handlers, because normal code is not prepared for the eeprom page to change mid-operation.

You can mix read and write operations, but that may lead to unnecessary wear on the EEPROM. You can, of course, split the read and write sides to separate caches, if you do mix reads and writes. That would also allow you to safely do EEPROM reads from an interrupt context (although the delay/latency of the I2C access might wreak havoc elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Not tailored specifically to your examples, completely untested and relying on having "read 4 bytes from EEPROM" and "write 16 bytes to EEPROM" encapsulated in suitable functions.

```
void write_to_eeprom(uint32_t start, size_t len, uint8_t *data) {
  uint32_t eeprom_dst = start & 0xfffffff0;
  uint8_t buffer[16];
  ssize_t data_offset;

  for (data_offset = (start - eeprom_dst); data_offset < len; data_offset += 16, eeprom_dst+= 16) {
    if (data_offset < 0) || ((len - data_offset) < 16) {
      // we need to fill our buffer with EEPROM data
      read_from_eeprom(eeprom_dst, buffer); // read 4 bytes, place at ptr
      read_from_eeprom(eeprom_dst+4, buffer+4);
      read_from_eeprom(eeprom_dst+8, buffer+8);
      read_from_eeprom(eeprom_dst+12, buffer+12);
      for (int buf_ix=0, ssize_t tmp_offset = data_offset; buf_ix < 16; buf_ix++, offset++) {
        if ((offset >= 0) && (buf_ix < 16)) {
          // We want to copy actual data
          buffer[buf_ix] = data[offset];
        }
      }
    } else {
      // We don't need to cater for edge cases and can simply shift
      // 16 bytes into our tmp buffer.
      for (int ix = 0; ix < 16; ix++) {
         buffer[ix] = data[data_offset + ix];
      }
    }
    write_to_eeprom(eeprom_dst, buffer);
  }
}
```